# Pass OneNote Authentication token to custom action

Tags: power-automate, onenote

I would like to delete a OneNote page in a Microsoft Flow. I appears there are no standard actions to do so, but I can call the DELETE api on the page that's passed in.

But, how do I obtain the bearer token from the OneNote connector?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need to extract authentication token from existing `Connection` as OneNote API is available via the Microsoft Graph API.

1. Authenticate using Bearer obtained from `/oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint using `grant_type=client_credentials` or any other flow
2. Get `Page ID` of desired document
3. Use one of HTTP `DELETE` methods described here https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/page-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs

[image: 1]]